# Show fragment and close it after a few seconds without user interactions

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to show a fragment for 5 seconds and then close it without the user interaction. This is my code.

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        listener.closeFragment(null);
                    }
                });
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }).run();
}
```

the `listener.closeFragment(null);`method works well (it close the fragment) but the fragment is never shown. Its like the thread runs before the fragment is visible. Any idea? is it posible?

Comment: how do you know that the fragment is visible when you start the thread?

Comment: why you are not using current code in Fragment which you want to show 5 second?

Comment: Does your Fragment has a layout?

Comment: You have to do your coding in fragment lifecycle...like once your fragment display then callback to activity, inside your activity close this fragment..

Comment: *Blackbelt: i dont know. How can i know?
*prosperK: Im using the inside the fragment i want to show.
*DroidBender: Yes, it does.
*@Androiddeveloper2011 thanks, I'll try it

Comment: My Mistake. I put run() instead of start(). Now it works. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you be using .start() instead of .run()?

You are just calling that that thread's logic sequentially.

Hope it helps.